# Usage of "Would like to meet you to"

Tags: word-choice

Is this the right way of asking to connect two people?

"I would like to meet you to my friend"

Comment: Nope.  "I would like to introduce you to my friend."

Comment: Do you mean "I would like to bring you and my friend together and let you get to know each other"? If you do then you say either "I would like to _introduce you to_ my friend" or "I would like you _to meet_ my friend".

Comment: Thanks, You have made the point clear.  I feel "I would like to introduce you to my friend" is the best option here.

Comment: You can say, when introducing someone, "I would like you to meet my friend".